I can't search in Messages on iOS anymore. How to fix it?
I haven't been able to search in Messages on my iPhone in months. When I try I get the following message: "No Results. More results will be shown once Messages finishes indexing." No advice I've found online has helped. What to do? Thanks.

If iCloud Messages is enabled, please disable it in Settings and test. If search works now, try re-enabling it.

What kind of advice did you find, what have you already tried to solve the problem?

Thanks. Turning off iCloud didn’t work. (It had been off when the problem started, so I tried activating it. No difference.) I can still see the “top hit” for a search term when I use the system-wide search setting, but I get nothing in-app. The advice from Apple was to restart, turn off and on iCloud and many of these other Message settings, etc.

It sounds like one or more of your messages from the time the problem started has content that is triggering a bug in the Spotlight importer for Messages. Do you keep messages permanently? If so, it might help to switch to deleting them automatically after 30 days. Alternatively, you could go through your old conversations and delete any you don't need to keep. Otherwise you may just have to wait for a macOS update to resolve the problem.

@nohillside I solved the problem. Am I allowed to answer my own question or is that against the rules? (I was criticized for doing this elsewhere.)

Sure, absolutely, please post an answer (and upvote/accept it).

Thanks. I posted it (I can’t accept it until tomorrow.) When searching I noticed many people seem to have this issue. I hope this will help.

That helps a lot (would have never thought of that). Thanks for coming back to post an answer.

I discovered the problem: lockdown mode. I had wanted to test it and never turned it off. Once I did so all my messages began indexing and I can now search them like normal.

If you set keep message permanently setting on then all messages should be store in your icloud account. There also a setting is icloud for imessage that shoul be turn on. On the other hand if other person delete nay message that he/she send to you, you could not able to find them by searching. If you thing the message are not deleted then try to reset your phone that will help to recover form apps bug.

Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to learn more about what we expect of answers.
